# Create a pdf in flex whith pdf alive for flex in 300dpi

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, pdf

Im trying to create a pdf in high resolution in 300dpi with pdf alive for flex, i used this code:

> var image:ImageSnapshot = ImageSnapshot.captureImage(page[i], 300, new JPEGEncoder());

but i create the pages with a loop for(), and this makes that my web aplication crashed, beacause it spend a lot of time to create the PDF.

Exist some way to create this process in the background but don’t want the .swf to freeze while the number crunching happens, or another way to create pdf in high resolution(300dpi) with flex.

Comment: Could you please include a code snippet that shows your for loop, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I use [fpdf](http://www.fpdf.org/) and find that it works great.  Check it out.  You can call it from flash (it uses php) and let it run.  I've used alivePDF also but found that I personally like fpdf better and was able to create much nicer PDF's with it but that could very well just be personal preference.